# linux set Consol

Tags: linux, windows, cursor-position

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences
I tried to use this site but I couldn't, can you help me?
this cod is running in windows system but i want to this code change linux. What should i do?
tetro is my class vector. I want it to go slowly down the map

```
for (int i = 0; i < tetro.size(); i++) {
        string tetrodemo = tetro[i].print();
        tetro[i].Board(board);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            COORD pos = { 1, (j + 1) };
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
            WriteConsoleA(hConsole, tetrodemo.c_str(), tetrodemo.size(), NULL, NULL);
            Sleep(WAIT_LOOP);
        }
```

Comment: Either rewrite it to use `cout`/`stdout` or find a library like `ncurses` that works for Linux terminals. All those CamelCaseFunctions are obviously from a Windows API, why would you expect them to work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.